# What is a place hold word?

Tags: nlp, nlp-question-answering

[image]

Hi i am trying to extract head words from a set of questions. I am implementing an algorithm mentioned in Huang et al., 2008 paper. In line 10 it says placehold-word. I cannot understand what a placehold word is. Can anyone help please.

Comment: [Choose one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder).

Comment: The term "Place holder" is generally used to indicate a text item that is intented to be replaced at a later time.

Comment: What are the "aforementioned regular expressions"? I'm guessing the text refers to a grammatical placeholder, such as a pronoun or other reference to an entity established in another part of the text.

Comment: those are the expressions at the left..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a language question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

okay i got it.
It means the word which is missing in the regular expression.
Example for pattern 2- What do/does _ mean?
so _ will be a place word.